# PowerShell list of both computer name and main user profile

Tags: powershell

Is there a way that I can input a list of both my computer names and then the main user profile along with it? I don't know if there is a way to associate the username with the computer name or if I have to do something else.

Example:
Computer names: Test1, Test2, Test3
User Profiles: Testing1, Testing2, Testing3
So Testing1 is on Test 1, Testing2 is on Test 2, and so on.
I am trying to go through all of the computer's main user instead of it going through all the users on the computer.

Below is what I have so far but this just runs through every profile on each computer.

```
foreach ($computer in (Get-Content c:\Users\TestUser\ComputerList.csv)) 
{
$userfolders = get-childitem "\\$Computer\C$\users\"
foreach ($user in $userfolders) {}
}
```

Could I make another list for the profile name and make it go through that or somehow associate it with the computer list?

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the profile of the same user on all machines, or will it be a different user per machine?

Comment: It will be different user per machine as the profile is associated with the AD user

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do; please edit your question to include more detail and/or examples of what you expect to see.

Comment: Just made an edit. Hope it helps clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like Mathias answer should be what youre looking for. As an alternative, you can try the using a `[pscustomobject]`.

```
foreach ($computer in (Get-Content c:\Users\TestUser\ComputerList.csv)) {
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -count 1){

$userfolders = get-childitem "\\$Computer\C$\users\"  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Computer = $computer
        Users = $userfolders
        } | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to store the associations in a hashtable:

```
$ProfileTargets = @{
  'Computer-01' = 'john'
  'Computer-02' = 'jane'
  'Computer-03' = 'joey'
}
```

Now you can iterate over the entries in the hashtable one by one:

```
foreach($target in $ProfileTargets.GetEnumerator()){
  $ComputerName = $target.Key
  $UserName = $target.Value
  $ProfilePath = "\\$ComputerName\C$\users\$UserName\"

  # do what you must with `$ProfilePath` here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the following but it didn't seem to work.       
    `$ProfileTargets = 
    @{
    'Test-PC' = 'Testing'
    }

    foreach($target in $ProfileTargets.GetEnumerator()){
    $ComputerName = $target.Key
    $UserName = $target.Value
    $ProfilePath = "\\$ComputerName\users\$UserName\"
    Remove-Item -Path "$ProfilePath\Test.msi"
    }`

Comment: The admin share `C$` is missing in the path.

Comment: Yup^, the hidden table needs to be specified. Add `c$`.

Comment: Yep, definitely forgot to add it. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any limit to how many items are in the hashtable?